# How are Facebook-shared YouTube video stats recorded?

Tags: facebook, youtube, statistics

Instead of sharing YouTube videos by clicking share button in YouTube, there is the possibility that one may just copy & paste the YouTube link and post it as status (and this allows one to see the video in Facebook currently). In this case, how are statistics reported? So the question is divided into two:

1. Are "share" statistics updated in this case?
2. If one watched the video through the Facebook status that has a video shared by the "non-standard" method, will views be updated accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

The views are broken down in Youtube's nifty statistics page per domain source, so you will be able to track where the video is being watched and where it is being shared. It is a pretty amazing tool for campaigns.

Comment: Where's that to be found?